# Wifi Network Adapter Not Connecting

Tags: wireless-networking

For the last week my laptop was not connecting to the wifi and the last two days, it wasn't connecting at all.
For a few weeks and intermittently I have been having to use the troubleshooter application to get a connection, but now these two days, this cannot fix it.

Would anyone think it is the network card itself that's burnt out or other??

Comment: Did you update wireless driver to the newest driver?  Open Device Manager (Control Panel) and expand the Network Section. Are there any yellow or red marks beside the wireless driver?

Comment: Yes John, every adapter in the network tab in the device manager. I think this is the first time I may have asked a question here since I joined this great website. I wanted to add that this laptop was a WinXP, then a Win7 and now a Win10 Inside. I upped the RAM to 8GB and the HardDrive.

Comment: I will get your answers a little later, got to hit the road.

Comment: XP computers are very old and may not be completely Windows 10 compliant. Run the Microsoft Upgrade adviser to see (Microsoft Downloads)

Comment: Windows10 Insiders have been posting system updates about three per week for about the last two months.
Do you think the upgrader would make that difference, because this is up to to date, even while I shared this post earlier yesterday, I will try and let you know.